# MSVC: Error mapping a structure to an array of offsetof

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to fill-in an array with the offset of structure field, I am trying to do the following

```
#define EXPAND_(X) X
#define TYPE_ARG_N(_0, _1, _2, N, ...) N
#define TYPE_OFFSET_1(S, _0) { sizeof(S), { offsetof(S, _0) } }
#define TYPE_OFFSET_2(S, _0, _1) { sizeof(S), { offsetof(S, _0), offsetof(S, _1) } }
#define TYPE_OFFSET_3(S, _0, _1, _2) { sizeof(S), { offsetof(S, _0), offsetof(S, _1), offsetof(S, _2) } }
#define TYPE_OFFSET_LIST() TYPE_OFFSET_3, TYPE_OFFSET_2, TYPE_OFFSET_1
#define TYPE_OFFSET_N_(...) EXPAND_(TYPE_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__))
#define TYPE_OFFSET_ARGS(...) EXPAND_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TYPE_OFFSET_SELECT(...) TYPE_OFFSET_N_(__VA_ARGS__, TYPE_OFFSET_LIST())
#define TYPE_OFFSET(S, ...) TYPE_OFFSET_SELECT(__VA_ARGS__)(S, TYPE_OFFSET_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))

typedef struct {
    size_t      size;
    size_t*     offsets;
} tTable;

tTable t = TYPE_OFFSET(tTable, size, offsets);
```

MSVC2017 fails with the following:

```
error C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'TYPE_OFFSET_2'
error C2065: 'offsets': undeclared identifier
error C2102: '&' requires l-value
```

Any idea on how to fix these macros ?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: @user0042 At first glance, the error message looks bogus to me, the number of arguments looks correct. But that's only at first glance.

Comment: @user0042 TYPE_OFFSET_2 is expecting 3 arguments and is getting 3 arguments. Since you understand the error, could you care to clarify it for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging things like this, try running things through *just* the preprocessor using the `/EP` flag.  Doing so with your code shows this output:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t      size;
    size_t*     offsets;
} tTable;

tTable t = fxma.h(17) : warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'TYPE_OFFSET_2'
{ sizeof(tTable), { offsetof(tTable, size, offsets), offsetof(tTable, ) } };
```

The problem here is that Microsoft's preprocessor has this notion of a single macro argument having commas in it.  This happens when the commas are produced by the expansion of another macro.

In particular, `TYPE_OFFSET` calls `TYPE_OFFSET_2` with `(tTable, size, offset)`, *but* `size, offset` together (being the expansion of `TYPE_OFFSET_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)`) isn't actually two different arguments... it's only 1.  `TYPE_OFFSET_2` then is getting only two arguments; in other words:

- `S` is `tTable1`
- `_0` is `size, offset`
- `_1` is missing

(You can see this in the expansion; `offsetof(tTable, size, offsets)`).

A fix is to add a level of indirection.  Replace your version of `TYPE_OFFSET` with this:

```
#define TYPE_OFFSET_CALL(X, Y) X Y
#define TYPE_OFFSET(S, ...) TYPE_OFFSET_CALL(TYPE_OFFSET_SELECT(__VA_ARGS__),(S, TYPE_OFFSET_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

Comment: Thanks, /EP helped a lot